# Building docker image error with proxy firewall

Tags: docker, pip, proxy, dockerfile, docker-image

Hello I have been trying to build an image however I am behind a proxy firewall, everytime I build using
docker build .
I get:
=> => # WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutE
=> => # rror(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1b264f8eb0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout
=> => # =15)')': /simple/requests/

I have already tried adding my proxy address to the docker proxy settings, have tried the --build-arg HTTP_PROXY= upon build command, and have also tried setting ENV htp_proxy= within my dockerfile right after my FROM command, however the issue still exists and I have not been able to find any other solutions. My dockerfile has RUN pip install requests beautifulsoup4 and thats where the docker build gets stuck since I am behind a corp firewall. Does anyone have any reccomendations?

Comment: Tried adding this to my RUN command still same issue, RUN pip install requests --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org

Answer (score 0):

You need to also pass the HTTPS_PROXY variable.

Comment: please check out my new post where I provide I have tried everything that has been suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68232512/16099568