# Docker firewall pip install errror

Tags: python, docker, pip, proxy

I have been trying to build a simple docker image however I am behind a corp firewall. I have tried all the steps below and nothing has worked.

*TRY 1:*
if I have nothing setup for proxy but the Docker Desktop -> Resources -> Proxies setting with my address and port and run

```
docker build -t python-imdb .
```

I get this:

```
 => => # WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTi
 => => # meoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f71033cb730>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (con
 => => # nect timeout=15)')': /simple/pyqt5/
```

4 times and then it stops with could not find a version that satisfies requirement pyqt5

*TRY 2:*
If I have nothing setup for proxy but the Docker Desktop -> Resources -> Proxies setting with my address and port and run
docker build  --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=address:port --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY=address:port -t python-imdb .

I get this:

```
#8 8.972 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f57bc6055e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))': /simple/pyqt5/
#8 8.985 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5 (from versions: none)
#8 8.985 ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyqt5
```

*TRY 3:*
If I have nothing setup for proxy but the Docker Desktop -> Resources -> Proxies setting with my address and port and run
docker build  --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=address:port -t python-imdb .

I get this:

```
 => => # WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTi
 => => # meoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0d31f56100>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (con
 => => # nect timeout=15)')': /simple/pyqt5/
```

I get this:

```
#8 8.972 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f57bc6055e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))': /simple/pyqt5/
#8 8.985 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5 (from versions: none)
#8 8.985 ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyqt5
```

*TRY 4:*
After updating docker file to this:
so my Dockerfile contains:

```py
FROM python:3.9

ENV HTTP_PROXY = "address:port"

ENV HTTPS_PROXY = "address:port"

ADD main.py .

RUN pip install pyqt5

CMD ["python", "./main.py"]
```

and running docker build -t python-imdb .

I get:

```
#7 8.965 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f787844faf0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))': /simple/pyqt5/
#7 8.986 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5 (from versions: none)
#7 8.986 ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyqt5
```

Answer (score 2):

If the proxy is configured correctly on your machine it should work with :

```
docker build --network=host -t python-imdb .
```

If it doesn't work, use [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) or [px](https://github.com/genotrance/px) to authenticate to the proxy.

Comment: Ive tried --network=host in my build but I get the same error. How can I check if the proxy is configured correctly on my machine? The only proxy settings I have setup is inside the Docker Desktop -> Resources -> Proxies

Comment: @ElgizAbbasov does a pip install work on your computer ? I'm guessing you need to authenticate to the proxy, use cntlm or px.

Comment: yes it does work if I put --proxy 127.0.0.1:portno as extra argument upon pip install. I have been trying various methods but I always get ProxyError